# Abstract Classes and Interfaces Java

Tags: java, interface, overloading, abstract

Class A

```
public abstract class AbstractA {
 public abstract void method1(int a);
 public void method2() {
 System.out.println("method2");
 } // end method2
 public abstract void method3();
}
```

Class B

```
public abstract class AbstractB {
 public abstract void method3();
 public abstract void method4();
}
```

Class C

```
public interface InterfaceC {
 void method1(int a, int b);
 void method2();
 void method4();
}
```

Test

```
public abstract class Choice3 extends AbstractA implements InterfaceC {
 public void method1(int a) {}
 public void method4() {}
} // end class
```

I'm very confused as to why Choice 3 actually compiles. It does overload method1(int a), but doesn't actually overload method1(inta intb).

Comment: Never mind, I just realized that its abstract so it doesn't need to override.

Answer (score 3):

```
public abstract class Choice3 extends AbstractA implements InterfaceC
```

when your class iself is abstract it need not to implement all methods of its direct/indirect abstract parent